# html: margins in and around select input

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reduce the margins between and within a couple of select boxes. So it is the margin between the selects and inside the select. If I shrink the width of the select, it cuts off the selected option but leaves the margin.

```
<html>
    <body>            
        <select>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I make this:
[image]

Look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set some cascading style sheet properties.  A negative margin on the second select box to the left and setting the padding to zero pixels should get you part of the way to where you want to go.  You may have to deal with operating system rendering differences at that point, however.

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/hN6Nw/) that worked on my system.

Comment: Better would be to **delete the whitespace** between the select elements, that way you don't need the ugly negative margin 'hack' -> 
http://jsfiddle.net/hN6Nw/158/

Comment: Sometimes it's better to our eyes (readability) to have them splitted in two lines so getting rid of the whitespace is not a good choice for these cases and I don't think that's semantically right. I'd preffer to follow the same negative margin approach but using "ems" instead of px or percentaje since these last ones are not relative to the font sizes. What about: `select + select { margin-left: -1em }`?

Answer (score 7):

It's realy dificult to style a `select` element because every browser make it different.
however I have change de `text-indent` and `width` properties to delete space IN the elelment.

```
select {
    margin: 0 -2px;
    text-indent:-2px;
    width: 38px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Too late but for those that have the same issue, just place some html comments between block. The problem is the same that you can have with inline-block blocks. If there is any character between two blocks, even a tabulation or a \n, you have whitespace on screen.

Solution:

-Put everything on one line:

```
<html>
<body>
    <select><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option<option>14</option</select><select><option>15</option><option>16</option><option>17</option><option>18</option></select>
</body>
```

-Put html comment between blocks:

```
<html>
    <body>            
        <select>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
        </select><!--
        --><select>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to adjust their paddings not their margin.

Answer (score 0):

In this example your change is related to the width and not padding or margin!

apply this class for example (try different widths until you get what you like):

```
.comboWidth {
   width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May this help you:

```
<select style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px">
```